# WebGL2: How to render via shaders onto a TEXTURE_3D

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, webgl2

I've read that WebGL2 gives us [access to 3d textures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext/texImage3D). I'm trying to use this to perform some GPU-side computations and then store the output in a 64x64x64 3D texture. The render flow is

`compute shader -> render to 3dTexture -> read shader -> render to screen`

This is my simple compute shader, the texture's RGB channels should correspond to the XYZ fragment coordinates.

```glsl
#version 300 es
precision mediump sampler3D;
precision highp float;
layout(location = 0) out highp vec4 pc_fragColor;

void main() {
    vec3 color = vec3(gl_FragCoord.x / 64.0, gl_FragCoord.y / 64.0, gl_FragDepth);
    pc_fragColor.rgb = color;
    pc_fragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

However, this only seems to be rendering to a single "slice" of the 3DTexture, where depth is 0.0. All subsequent depths from 1 to 63 px remain black:

[image]

I've created a working demo below to demonstrate this issue.

```js
var renderer, target3d, camera;
const SIDE = 64;
var computeMaterial, computeMesh;
var readDataMaterial, readDataMesh, 
    read3dTargetMaterial, read3dTargetMesh;
var textField = document.querySelector("#textField");

function init() {
    // Three.js boilerplate
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x000000), 1.0);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    camera = new THREE.Camera();

    // Create volume material to render to 3dTexture
    computeMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader: SIMPLE_VERTEX,
        fragmentShader: COMPUTE_FRAGMENT,
        uniforms: {
            uZCoord: { value: 0.0 },
        },
        depthTest: false,
    });
    computeMaterial.type = "VolumeShader";
    computeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2), computeMaterial);

    // Left material, reads Data3DTexture
    readDataMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader: SIMPLE_VERTEX,
        fragmentShader: READ_FRAGMENT,
        uniforms: {
            uZCoord: { value: 0.0 },
            tDiffuse: { value: create3dDataTexture() }
        },
        depthTest: false
    });
    readDataMaterial.type = "DebugShader";
    readDataMesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2), readDataMaterial);

    // Right material, reads 3DRenderTarget texture
    target3d = new THREE.WebGL3DRenderTarget(SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
    target3d.depthBuffer = false;

    read3dTargetMaterial = readDataMaterial.clone();
    read3dTargetMaterial.uniforms.tDiffuse.value = target3d.texture;
    read3dTargetMesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2), read3dTargetMaterial);
}

// Creates 3D texture with RGB gradient along the XYZ axes
function create3dDataTexture() {
    const d = new Uint8Array( SIDE * SIDE * SIDE * 4 );
    window.dat = d;
    let i4 = 0;

    for ( let z = 0; z < SIDE; z ++ ) {
        for ( let y = 0; y < SIDE; y ++ ) {
            for ( let x = 0; x < SIDE; x ++ ) {
                d[i4 + 0] = (x / SIDE) * 255;
                d[i4 + 1] = (y / SIDE) * 255;
                d[i4 + 2] = (z / SIDE) * 255;
                d[i4 + 3] = 1.0;
                i4 += 4;
            }
        }
    }

    const texture = new THREE.Data3DTexture( d, SIDE, SIDE, SIDE );
    texture.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
    texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    texture.unpackAlignment = 1;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    return texture;
}

function onResize() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate(t) {
    // Render volume shader to target3d buffer
    renderer.setRenderTarget(target3d);
    renderer.render(computeMesh, camera);

    // Update z texture coordinate along sine wave
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    const sinZCoord = Math.sin(t / 1000);
    readDataMaterial.uniforms.uZCoord.value = sinZCoord;
    read3dTargetMaterial.uniforms.uZCoord.value = sinZCoord;
    textField.innerText = sinZCoord.toFixed(4);

    // Render data3D texture to screen
    renderer.setViewport(0, window.innerHeight - SIDE*4, SIDE * 4, SIDE * 4);
    renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
    renderer.render(readDataMesh, camera);

    // Render 3dRenderTarget texture to screen
    renderer.setViewport(SIDE * 4, window.innerHeight - SIDE*4, SIDE * 4, SIDE * 4);
    renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
    renderer.render(read3dTargetMesh, camera);

    renderer.autoClear = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

init();
window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
h3 {
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
    <h3>texDepth</h3><h3 id="textField"></h3>
</div>
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Compute frag shader
// It should output an RGB gradient in the XYZ axes to the 3DRenderTarget
// But gl_FragCoord.z is always 0.5 and gl_FragDepth is always 0.0

const COMPUTE_FRAGMENT = `#version 300 es
precision mediump sampler3D;
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
layout(location = 0) out highp vec4 pc_fragColor;

void main() {
    vec3 color = vec3(gl_FragCoord.x / 64.0, gl_FragCoord.y / 64.0, gl_FragDepth);
    pc_fragColor.rgb = color;
    pc_fragColor.a = 1.0;
}`;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Reader frag shader
// Samples the 3D texture along uv.x, uv.y, and uniform Z coordinate

const READ_FRAGMENT = `#version 300 es
precision mediump sampler3D;
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
layout(location = 0) out highp vec4 pc_fragColor;

in vec2 vUv;
uniform sampler3D tDiffuse;
uniform float uZCoord;

void main() {
    vec3 UV3 = vec3(vUv.x, vUv.y, uZCoord);
    vec3 diffuse = texture(tDiffuse, UV3).rgb;
    pc_fragColor.rgb = diffuse;
    pc_fragColor.a = 1.0;
}
`;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Simple vertex shader,
// renders a full-screen quad with UVs without any transformations
const SIMPLE_VERTEX = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
precision highp int;

in vec2 uv;
in vec3 position;
out vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}`;


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

</script>
```

- On the left side, I’m sampling a Data3DTexture that I created via JavaScript. The blue channel smoothly transitions as I move up and down the depth axis, as expected.
- On the right side I’m sampling the WebGL3DRenderTarget texture rendered in the frag shader I showed above. As you can see, it's only rendering to the texture when the depth coordinate is 0.0. All the other “slices” are black.

[image]
[image]

How can I render my computations to all 64 depth slices? I'm using Three.js for this demo, but I could use any other library like [TWGL](https://twgljs.org/) or vanilla WebGL to achieve the same results.

Comment: "*However, this only seems to be rendering to a single "slice" of the 3DTexture, where depth is 0.0. All subsequent depths from 1 to 63 px remain black*" Well... yeah. That's how rendering to a mipmap level of a 3D texture works. You attach a particular depth layer to the FBO; that's your render target. Did you expect `gl_FragDepth` to map to the 3D texture's depth component?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I used that as a jumping-off point because I don't know how to do it. I also tried `gl_FragCoord.z`, which always gave me a value of `0.5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look documented but you can use a second argument to `setRenderTarget` to set the "layer" of the 3d render target to render to. Here are the changes to make:

1. When rendering to the render target perform a new render for every layer:

```
for ( let i = 0; i < SIDE; i ++ ) {
   
  // set the uZCoord color value for the shader
  computeMesh.material.uniforms.uZCoord.value = i / (SIDE - 1);

  // Set the 3d target "layer" to render into before rendering
  renderer.setRenderTarget(target3d, i);
  renderer.render(computeMesh, camera);

}
```

2. Use the "uZCoord" uniform in the compute fragment shader:

```
    uniform float uZCoord;
    void main() {
        vec3 color = vec3(gl_FragCoord.x / 64.0, gl_FragCoord.y / 64.0, uZCoord);
        pc_fragColor.rgb = color;
        pc_fragColor.a = 1.0;
    }
```

Other than that I don't believe theres a way to render to the full 3d volume of the target in a single draw call. This three.js example shows how to do this but with render target arrays, as well:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=array#webgl2_rendertarget_texture2darray

```js
var renderer, target3d, camera;
const SIDE = 64;
var computeMaterial, computeMesh;
var readDataMaterial, readDataMesh, 
    read3dTargetMaterial, read3dTargetMesh;
var textField = document.querySelector("#textField");

function init() {
    // Three.js boilerplate
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x000000), 1.0);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    camera = new THREE.Camera();

    // Create volume material to render to 3dTexture
    computeMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader: SIMPLE_VERTEX,
        fragmentShader: COMPUTE_FRAGMENT,
        uniforms: {
            uZCoord: { value: 0.0 },
        },
        depthTest: false,
    });
    computeMaterial.type = "VolumeShader";
    computeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2), computeMaterial);

    // Left material, reads Data3DTexture
    readDataMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader: SIMPLE_VERTEX,
        fragmentShader: READ_FRAGMENT,
        uniforms: {
            uZCoord: { value: 0.0 },
            tDiffuse: { value: create3dDataTexture() }
        },
        depthTest: false
    });
    readDataMaterial.type = "DebugShader";
    readDataMesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2), readDataMaterial);

    // Right material, reads 3DRenderTarget texture
    target3d = new THREE.WebGL3DRenderTarget(SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
    target3d.depthBuffer = false;

    read3dTargetMaterial = readDataMaterial.clone();
    read3dTargetMaterial.uniforms.tDiffuse.value = target3d.texture;
    read3dTargetMesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2), read3dTargetMaterial);
}

// Creates 3D texture with RGB gradient along the XYZ axes
function create3dDataTexture() {
    const d = new Uint8Array( SIDE * SIDE * SIDE * 4 );
    window.dat = d;
    let i4 = 0;

    for ( let z = 0; z < SIDE; z ++ ) {
        for ( let y = 0; y < SIDE; y ++ ) {
            for ( let x = 0; x < SIDE; x ++ ) {
                d[i4 + 0] = (x / SIDE) * 255;
                d[i4 + 1] = (y / SIDE) * 255;
                d[i4 + 2] = (z / SIDE) * 255;
                d[i4 + 3] = 1.0;
                i4 += 4;
            }
        }
    }

    const texture = new THREE.Data3DTexture( d, SIDE, SIDE, SIDE );
    texture.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
    texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    texture.unpackAlignment = 1;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    return texture;
}

function onResize() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate(t) {
    for ( let i = 0; i < SIDE; i ++ ) {
   
      // Render volume shader to target3d buffer
      computeMesh.material.uniforms.uZCoord.value = i / ( SIDE - 1 );
      renderer.setRenderTarget(target3d, i);
      renderer.render(computeMesh, camera);

    } 

    // Update z texture coordinate along sine wave
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    const sinZCoord = Math.sin(t / 1000);
    readDataMaterial.uniforms.uZCoord.value = sinZCoord;
    read3dTargetMaterial.uniforms.uZCoord.value = sinZCoord;
    textField.innerText = sinZCoord.toFixed(4);

    // Render data3D texture to screen
    renderer.setViewport(0, window.innerHeight - SIDE*4, SIDE * 4, SIDE * 4);
    renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
    renderer.render(readDataMesh, camera);

    // Render 3dRenderTarget texture to screen
    renderer.setViewport(SIDE * 4, window.innerHeight - SIDE*4, SIDE * 4, SIDE * 4);
    renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
    renderer.render(read3dTargetMesh, camera);

    renderer.autoClear = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

init();
window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
h3 {
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
    <h3>texDepth</h3><h3 id="textField"></h3>
</div>
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Compute frag shader
// It should output an RGB gradient in the XYZ axes to the 3DRenderTarget
// But gl_FragCoord.z is always 0.5 and gl_FragDepth is always 0.0

const COMPUTE_FRAGMENT = `#version 300 es
precision mediump sampler3D;
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
layout(location = 0) out highp vec4 pc_fragColor;

uniform float uZCoord;
void main() {
    vec3 color = vec3(gl_FragCoord.x / 64.0, gl_FragCoord.y / 64.0, uZCoord);
    pc_fragColor.rgb = color;
    pc_fragColor.a = 1.0;
}`;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Reader frag shader
// Samples the 3D texture along uv.x, uv.y, and uniform Z coordinate

const READ_FRAGMENT = `#version 300 es
precision mediump sampler3D;
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
layout(location = 0) out highp vec4 pc_fragColor;

in vec2 vUv;
uniform sampler3D tDiffuse;
uniform float uZCoord;

void main() {
    vec3 UV3 = vec3(vUv.x, vUv.y, uZCoord);
    vec3 diffuse = texture(tDiffuse, UV3).rgb;
    pc_fragColor.rgb = diffuse;
    pc_fragColor.a = 1.0;
}
`;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Simple vertex shader,
// renders a full-screen quad with UVs without any transformations
const SIMPLE_VERTEX = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
precision highp int;

in vec2 uv;
in vec3 position;
out vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}`;


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

</script>
```